# Extract last part from string

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have a string, which looks like this:

```
local string = 'VALUE1_VALUE2_VALUE3_VALUE4'
```

I would like to get the VALUE4 only using string.match. How can i do this?

Comment: `string.match(string, ".*_(.*)")`

Comment: `string:match"_(.-)$"`, `string:match"_?(.-)$"` if you want it to handle delimited strings of only one value `VALUE`.

Answer (score 2):

This matches VALUE4 at the end of a string

```
print(str:match("VALUE4$"))
```

For a more general solution you can do something like this:

```
print(str:match("%w+$"))
```

Match a sequence of alphanumeric characters at the end of your string.

It is not clear what you are actually trying to do. But this should give you a starting point. Please refer to the Lua manual.